# ReactTS parallel api request calls for zip files download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading, nestjs

I am using React TS, with Nestjs as backend.

**Context**

I have a function `downloadZip(csvProps)`:
Input - Parameters for csv files and url for API requests; Output- Zip file containing 4 csv files

```
const downloadZip = async (csvProps: any, urlParams: any) => {
        let zip = new JSZip();

        let csv = zip.folder("csv");

        //English Data CSV
        let enDataBlob = await downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchData`, urlParams,
            {...csvProps, filename: 'Data_en', columns: headers_data_en, wrapColumnChar: '"'})
        csv?.file('Data_en.csv', enDataBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

        //French Data CSV
        let frDataBlob = await downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchData`, urlParams,
            {...csvProps, filename: 'Data_fr', columns: headers_data_fr, wrapColumnChar: '"'})
        csv?.file('Data_fr.csv', frDataBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

        //English Flow CSV
        let enFlowBlob = await downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchFlow`, urlParams,
            {...csvProps, filename: 'Flow_en', columns: headers_flow_en, wrapColumnChar: '"'})
        csv?.file('Flow_en.csv', enFlowBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

        //French Flow CSV
        let frFlowBlob = await downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchFlow`, urlParams,
            {...csvProps, filename: 'Flow_fr', columns: headers_flow_fr, wrapColumnChar: '"'})
        csv?.file('Flow_fr.csv', frFlowBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

        zip.generateAsync(({type: "blob"}))
            .then((content) => {
                saveAs(content, csvProps.filename)
            })
    }
```

The `downloadCSV(url: string, urlParams: any, csvProps: any)` function used above is simply to make an axios request to the backend, and return a csv blob generated from the response:

```
export const downloadCSV = async (apiURL: string, urlParams: any, csvProps: any) => {
    let csvBlob: Blob|undefined;
    let api = await axios.get(apiURL, {
        params: urlParams
      })
    .then(async (res) => {
        // handleCSV: Gets all CSV related data and returns a csv Blob
        csvBlob = await handleCSV({...csvProps, datas: res.data});
    })
    return csvBlob
}
```

Since I am using `async-await`, the api requests and consequent blob generation processes are happening sequentially, and the performance is being impacted.

**Question**

Is there a way I can make these processes parallel? I want all the files to be processed in parallel, and then eventually added to the zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `await`ing each API call, you could do `Promise.all(apiCalls)` and await the result of that, letting the result be an array of values returned from the API. Something like

```js
const downloadZip = async (csvProps: any, urlParams: any) => {
  let zip = new JSZip();

  let csv = zip.folder("csv");
  const apiCalls = [
    downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchData`, urlParams,
      {...csvProps, filename: 'Data_en', columns: headers_data_en, wrapColumnChar: '"'}),
    downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchData`, urlParams,
      {...csvProps, filename: 'Data_fr', columns: headers_data_fr, wrapColumnChar: '"'}),
    downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchFlow`, urlParams,
      {...csvProps, filename: 'Flow_en', columns: headers_flow_en, wrapColumnChar: '"'}),
    downloadCSV(`${ServerService.getUrl()}/fetchFlow`, urlParams,
      {...csvProps, filename: 'Flow_fr', columns: headers_flow_fr, wrapColumnChar: '"'}),
  ];
  const [enDataBlob, frDataBlob, enFlowBlob, frFlowBlob] = await Promise.all(apiCalls);
  //English Data CSV
  csv?.file('Data_en.csv', enDataBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

  //French Data CSV
  csv?.file('Data_fr.csv', frDataBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

  //English Flow CSV
  csv?.file('Flow_en.csv', enFlowBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

  //French Flow CSV
  csv?.file('Flow_fr.csv', frFlowBlob as Blob, {base64: true})

  zip.generateAsync(({type: "blob"}))
    .then((content) => {
      saveAs(content, csvProps.filename)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually ended up taking this approach but right in the NestJS backend.